# IE9 Browser issues while running selenium web driver scripts "browser is not responding due to a long-running script"

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am getting below errors, can anyone help me out to solve this errors and I have tried with few things even though getting same

1. xxxx (url name) browser is not responding due to a long-running script
2. xxxx (url name) is not responding
3. A problem with this webpage caused IE to close and reopen the tab

i have tried with below changes

By resting ie9 settings
By deleting cache, history and temp files.
By re installing ie9
By selecting "User software rendering instead of GPU rendering” in IE options (Advanced tab)
By installing "MicrosoftFixit50403.msi"
By Adding "DWord value" to max (ffffffff) in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\IE\Style
By selecting IE compatibility mode settings
By removing add-on except java in IE options - programs - manage add-ons
By selecting the Disable script debugging check box in IE options
Click to clear the Display a notification about every script error check box.

For every change I have restarted pc and tried.

Environments which I have tried

Windows 7 ie9 64 bit and 32 bit
Java 11.0-b16
Selenium server standalone 2.35.0 and also tried with 2.37.0

Windows 7 patch on windows vista ie9 64 bit and 32 bit
Java 11.0-b16
Selenium server standalone 2.35.0 and also tried with 2.37.0

Please help on this, Thanks in advance.

Regards
Raghavendra

Comment: What version of the IE driver?

Comment: Hi Arran, i am using IEDriver_Server : 2.33.0

Comment: That is around 6 months old. Please update it. (May not be the issue but you should rule it out first)

Comment: i have done as u said, after one hour execution getting same error dialog.

Comment: May not be the same issue, but by installing this fix, i could solve similar issue. Refer here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500

Comment: hi i have done it already and i have  mentioned in my query also but no use getting same error